# How to make vertical menu using jsf?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

i m developing a web page, where i want to show vertical menu. when any clicks on menu its content should open on same page inside a box, and on clicking next menu new content should open in same place . I m using java ,JSP,JSF, java script.. can any one help me on.....

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

```
  $("#myLink").click(function() {
      $(this).fancybox({href : 'temp.jsp'});
  });
```

});

Open ajax content

I have tried this but i need to design lots of jsps.

Comment: Which jsf version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

use [primefaces menu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu.jsf), it has all the fancy you need

Comment: I have tried Prime Faces as well Rich Faces, But not able to find correct tag. can you suggest some...

Comment: @user2303824 just check the provided link?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try RichFaces - rich:dropDownMenu and rich:popupPanel

[rich:dropDownMenu - RichFaces Showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dropDownMenu&skin=blueSky)

[rich:popupPanel - RichFaces Showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&sample=simplePopup&skin=blueSky)